# Accessing all inner elements in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have:

```
<k-myelement>
    <k-anotherelement></k-anotherelement>
</k-myelement>
```

When I define the template like this:

```
<polymer-element name="k-myelement">
    <template>
        <content select="k-anotherelement" id="anotherelement"></content>
    </template>
</polymere-element>
```

I can access the inner element with `this.$['anotherelement']`

But with this approach I have to predefine, which inner elements can be used.

What I want is a template technique, that allows me to access all the inner elements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`<content>` ([insertion points](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/#toc-separation-separate)) are for rendering elements in the light DOM at specific locations in the Shadow DOM. Using `<content select="k-anotherelement"></content>` says "render any `<k-anotherelement>` elements here. If you want all light DOM nodes to be invited into the rendering party, simply use `<content></<content>`.

The other issues with your snippet:

- The name of the element needs to be defined on `<polymer-element>`, not as `<template name="k-myelement">`
- To get the list of nodes that pass through a `<content>`, use `content.getDistributedNodes()`. You may also want to consider if you even need `<content>`. Light DOM children nodes can be access with `.children` and the other accessors. From [the Polymer docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#accessContentDOM):

  > For a `<content>`, you can iterate through `content.getDistributedNodes()` to get the list of nodes distributed at the insertion point.
  >
  > In Polymer, the best place to call this method is in the `attached()` callback so you’re guaranteed that the element is in the DOM tree.
  >
  > Also remember that you can access the light DOM as the element’s normal children (i.e. `this.children`, or other accessors). The difference with this approach is that it’s the entire set of potentially distributed nodes; not those actually distributed.

Comment: ah yes, I wrote it in the `<polymer-element>` tag not in the `<template>` (like I did here). I thought the light DOM elements would get deleted after the shadow DOM elements get added and I would have to grab them anytime before this happens. Thank you.