# How do I select nodes in Polymer without using ID?

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer

I'd like to use the content multiple times, but in different arrangements. Simply copying all content child nodes into each occurrence (as seen here: [Polymer Duplicate Element Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420695/polymer-duplicate-element-content)) won't do the trick, and I can't use the querySelector for ID, since each content child node is supposed to be copied into multiple elements.

index.html:

```
...
<body>
    <my-list>
        <div class="first">This is first.</div>
        <div class="second">This is second.</div>
        <div class="third">This is third.</div>
    </my-list>
</body>
```

So I'd want something like this for my my-list.html, but I don't know how to select elements that don't have an ID:

```
<dom-module id="my-list">
    <template>
        <div>
            <div class="first"></div>
            <div class="second"></div>
            <div class="third"></div>
        </div>
        <div> <!-- same elements, different layout -->
            <div class="second"></div>
            <div class="third"></div>
            <div class="first"></div>
        </div>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "my-list",
        domReady: function() {
            // copy each content child node into the divs with the same class
        }
    });
</script>
```

There's no interaction on the page, so I'm not concerned about data binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Polymer.dom(node). An example would be

```
Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('.first');
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact, querySelectorAll() seems to be what I was looking for.